# Update Preview button is throwing error "invalid URI: tcm:0-0-0"

Tags: web8.5, experience-manager

I am experiencing one issue that once I click on the "Update Preview" button in Site Edit mode, then it always asks me to load the preview update also sometimes through the error "Invalid URI: tcm-0-0-0".

**For reference:** I have recently upgraded to SDL 8.5 microservices.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar issues, it’s because of XPM markup tag ComponentTemplateID is empty on that page some of the components, that is why it’s throwing the Invalid URI error while Finishing Editing in XPM inline while updating the preview button.

You can check these values in view source of the page to see those markup page, you can also see in the chrome debug developer tool or fiddler to see that post request of the values, It could be your content model has a component link field it's not handled properly rendering the XPM.

At the end, you need to review your source code of XPM tag implementation further to fix this issue on the web app side.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually, XPM working earlier and once I upgraded to microservices then I am getting this error, for your reference, I have checked markup is correct and have componentTemplateID

Comment: then, worth validate your setup - https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2018/03/23/troubleshooting-the-experience-manager-xpm-for-sdl-tridion-web-8-5-with-dxa-2-0/

Comment: I have validated setup as per the above link, all good at my end, Just for more update, I am using SDL web8.5 with DD4T Java,

Comment: For XPM, important is markup tags and values, since you mentioned it's happening very often, is that happening specific page?

Comment: It's happening on every page if I do not click on the "Update Preview" button and click on Finish editing then its save and after publish, I can see updates on site too.

Comment: You mean to say only update preview button click is the issue, that it's only happening very often? the same page sometimes works?

Comment: It's not very often its always, I mean to say, If I do not click on preview button and do only finish editing, then it's working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101601/discussion-between-velmurugan-and-priyank-gupta).